# How can i change the date format when echoing a database field?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an html input field with a php echo in it. The echo reads from a database field with a timestamp. I need to change the format of the outputted date.

The database has the default 'datetime' sql field and format.

How can i change this to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm?

I have tried reading the docs on changing a date via php but because of the variable and database field, i dn't seem to be able to formulate it correctly.

Here is an example of a field i'm trying to change:-

```
<?php echo $update->micp_edit_TIMESTAMP; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty

```
//asumming this is a DATETIME field in your database
echo date('d/m/Y H:i', strtotime($update->micp_edit_TIMESTAMP));
```

If you use MySQL use @Curious_Mind 's answer

Comment: Thanks. This one is perfect for our code and working well.

Answer (score 3):

You can select the value from database with proper format if you want. Let's try like this way using `DATE_FORMAT()`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(your_column_name, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') FROM your_tablename
```

Comment: Note to readers, [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) is specific to MySQL. Since (at the time of writing) this question is not tagged with a specific DBMS, it may be that the OP is not using MySQL and will have to research what the correct date formatting function is called in their environment.

Comment: Thank you @Curious_Mind, i am using MySQL and have now tagged the question appropriately.

Comment: @LeeColarelli no prob. Glad it helps you somehow. Best of luck :)

Comment: Thanks again. This is a good answer but unfortunately did not fit with how our code is.

Answer (score 0):

As per php manual:

Object oriented style

```
<?php
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Procedural style

```
<?php
    $date = date_create_from_format('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
    echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
?>
```

The above examples will output:

2009-02-15

See: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

You can adapt the examples to use the formats you have and require by looking in the manual which explains the format strings. And of course substitute the variables by your own variables.